# How to insert user input into send() with GET

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, get, user-input, send

I'm trying to use user input in a GET request with send(), but I keep getting an error message: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str. Is there a way around this? The input is already converted to bytes.

```
import socket


response = input("Enter a valid URL: ")
try:
    soc_open = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tray = list(response.split('/'))
    in_bytes = bytes(response, 'utf-8')
    soc_open.connect((tray[2], 80))
    print("Worked!")
    soc_open.close()
except:
    print("ERROR: Invalid URL")
    exit()

cmd = 'GET '+ (in_bytes) +' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
soc_open.send(cmd)

while True:
    data = soc_open.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
      break
    print(data.decode(),end='')

soc_open.close()
```

Comment: `'GET '` is a str, not bytes. However, `b'GET '` is bytes.

Comment: I used: `cmd = b'GET ' + (in_bytes) + b' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'
soc_open.send(cmd)` , but I got an error: OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are `close()`'ing your socket after `connect()` and before `send()`. Also, if you need to send a mix of strings and bytes, just `send()` them separately, you don't need to concatenate them first. TCP is just a byte stream, after all: `soc_open.send('GET '.encode()) soc_open.send(in_bytes) soc_open.send(' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode())`.  Though, in this case, concatenation makes more sense if you DON'T encode `response` to bytes right away: `cmd = 'GET ' + response + ' HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' soc_open.send(bytes(cmd, 'utf-8'))`